# How to use id field to track specific data php

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to take data from mysql database and printing it out into a table. This has been successful. There is suppose to be a specific details screen for each individual 'Chess Game' with details about that one and only that one specific game on that page.

How do I set an id to my `<a href="details.php>` tag that will keep track of each specific id for that given game.

```
    <form method="post" action="extra.php">
Date Range From:
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" value="">
To:
<input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" value="">
<br/>
Name Search:
<input type="text" id="nameSearch" name="nameSearch" value="">
<br/>
Game Result:
<select name="gameResult">
    <option value="any">Any</option>
    <option value="p1">Player 1</option>
    <option value="p2">Player 2</option>
    <option value="draw">Draw</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<?php

include('../inclass/db_connect.php');
//Dates are filled in
if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b) ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(matchDate, '%m/%Y/%d') desc LIMIT 250");

    $result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
    $result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
    $result->execute();

//Dates and Search for Name filled in
if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo']) && ($_POST['nameSearch'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b) AND ((player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%')) LIMIT 250");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
    $result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
    $result->execute();
}
//Dates search for name and p1 picked for results 
if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo']) && ($_POST['nameSearch']) && ($_POST['gameResult'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];
    $gameResult = $_POST['gameResult'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b) AND ((player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%')) AND (result ='1') LIMIT 250");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
    $result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
    $result->execute();
}

//Dates search for name and p2 picked for results
if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo']) && ($_POST['nameSearch']) && ($_POST['gameResult'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];
    $gameResult = $_POST['gameResult'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b) AND ((player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%')) AND (result ='2') LIMIT 250");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
    $result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
    $result->execute();
}

//Dates search for name and Draw picked for results
if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo']) && ($_POST['nameSearch']) && ($_POST['gameResult'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];
    $gameResult = $_POST['gameResult'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN :a AND :b) AND ((player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%')) AND (result ='D') LIMIT 250");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $dateFrom);
    $result->bindParam(':b', $dateTo);
    $result->execute();
}

    ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Match Date</th>
        <th>Player 1</th>
        <th>Player 2</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>ECO Code</th>
        <th>Match Details</th>
    </tr>
<?php
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['matchDate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['result']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['eco']; ?></td>
        **<td><a href="details.php" id=".$row['id'].">Details</a></td>**
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
    $dateFrom = 0;
    $dateTo = 0;
    $nameSearch = 0;
    $gameResult = 0;
}
```

This is the code for the initial screen showing the Chess Games. Here is a working link with it http://cps276.net/zgambrell/04/extra.php , I have been using 2000/06/06 to 2001/06/06 for the dates i use to view the chess games that occurred in that time period. I just need help not displaying ALL the details about ALL of the chess games on the details page. PLEASE HELP!

I tried to break this question down best I could to make sense of it.

Comment: Instead of only using PHP to fill in values, you can straight out write HTML with PHP: `<?php echo "<td id=" . $someId . "\">" . $someContent . "</td>"; ?>`

Comment: How does that create a different id for each 'game' or row of data that is created so that the details page only shows the data from the one specific game?

Comment: The id should be coming from your database. Never create IDs client side that you plan on storing as a pk in your db - a bad client could easy cause issues.

Comment: `<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">`, glad to see a beginner not using a deprecated library, but you should not use variables directly on your query `LIKE '$nameSearch%` to avoid SQL injection and properly sanitize it!

Comment: @Prix: the paramater should have a name, like: `<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">`

Comment: @yangsunny was just illustrating the difference and technically no, you don't need the parameter name to read it.